# Keep getting a CORS error for put requests in Django from browser

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, cors, put

I keep getting a CORS error when I make a put request to my Django server from my frontend application (Fetch API) but not from Postman. Here is the error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://q72y0iroi2.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/weightsheets/636. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 503.

Somehow GET, POST and DELETE requests are working fine.

I have tried all the settings suggested in the documentation for django-cors-headers but to no avail!

Any advice would be highly appreciated

Here is my settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("DJANGO_SECRET_KEY", get_random_secret_key())

DEBUG = os.getenv("DEBUG", "False")

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

DEVELOPMENT_MODE = os.getenv("DEVELOPMENT_MODE", "False")


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'corsheaders',
    'weighttrackingapi',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
}

# List of allowed origins

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    "DELETE",
    "GET",
    "OPTIONS",
    "PATCH",
    "POST",
    "PUT",
)

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    "accept",
    "authorization",
    "content-type",
    "user-agent",
    "x-csrftoken",
    "x-requested-with",
)
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True



MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


ROOT_URLCONF = 'weighttracking.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'weighttracking.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'railway',
        'USER' : 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD' : '*****************',
        'HOST' : 'containers-us-west-11.railway.app',
        'PORT' : '7866',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True



STATIC_URL = 'static/'
# STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_ROOT =os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders', # <-------- this
    'myapp',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', # <-------- this
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'sales_company_app.get_user_instance.RequestMiddleware',
]



REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
}


CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True # <-------- this
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",    # React (FrontEnd Url) # <-------- this
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = '*' # <-------- this
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["http://192.168.1.155:8000/"] # (Api Base Url) <-------- this
```

#### NOTE - Make sure must installed (pip install django-cors-headers)

Comment: Tried it - still doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: I already had CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True further below, but I tried what you suggested and still no luck! (Thanks a ton for your help though)

Comment: Frontend side react ??

Comment: Yes I have react on the frontend.

Comment: The answer is updated (on my side this config working fine)

Comment: CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS are enough to prevent cors origin error.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your site to the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header and you'll be fine. Just do something like

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: url/of/your/domain
```

or

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

I would not recommend doing the bottom one unless you know what you are doing.

Reference would be this: [CORS error code 503](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin)

Comment: Any thoughts on how to do that in a Django app?

Comment: Depends where you have hosted, is it a local server or some thing else? 
It is quite difficult to say without looking at what you're even trying to do.